# What type of ir sensor does the Wii remote use?

Tags: sensors, ir

I am wondering what type of sensor the Wii remote works. I don't mean a specific model, but rather the general name of the type of sensor. I am looking in the end for a newer version

Comment: Hi, welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange. You would have better success and reachability about this particular questions and forums - you can try electronics stackexchange for example, which is a SE site more dedicated to electronics and embedded systems.

Comment: @ssarkar thanks